# Audio Recognition using python

Tags: python, fingerprint, audio-fingerprinting

I am working on a group project. We are looking to develop a program that can receive audio via laptop microphone and compare it to a saved audio file and output a audio message if the input and saved files match. Audios may be speeches, music or songs.

We would like to compare audio files with some sort of python method, but we haven't been able to find any way to do this. We are looking for a library of some sort or another to be able to take data from each file and see if they are similar.

We have watched a lot of tutorials, searched the web and still need some major help. Could someone explain to us how to get started?

Comment: take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/resemble-ai/resemblyzer)

Comment: If you are trying to make something similar to Shazam, then I would recommend you to take a look at the [audio-fingerprint-identifying-python](https://github.com/itspoma/audio-fingerprint-identifying-python) repo

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This suggests a range of needs too broad for Stack Overflow.  It's a perfectly valid place to be, but it's out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing audios, Try converting audio to spectrogram using python of both audio files & Compare both images. You can best results.

But if you want to process only audio files Yes, there some libraries which you can use.

```
1. Librosa - Python library for audio and music analysis
```

[link](https://librosa.github.io/) for Librosa

Answer (score 2):

Try project [dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu), it really helps. It's based on Numpy.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please add a link to external projects and resources. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

However, if you just want to filter audio files, Yes, there are some python libraries you can use.
Here is the link for one;

https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

or use pip install SpeechRecognition to install

Hope this solves your problem.